# Update row instead of adding new row

Tags: javascript, php

My problem is I want to update the row but when I edit the row, it will add new row and some data not retrieve back into database. Anyone know that I'm missing something? Should I add some loop? I'm using button submit and in button submit I just want the function editGroup (update) only for the same row. It means, the user can edit the row and click button submit and row be updated.

> PHP update

```
function editGroup(){
global $ehorsObj;
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$accountID        = (isset($_POST['accountID']) ? $_POST['accountID'] : '');
$accountLedgerID  = (isset($_POST['accountLedgerID']) ? $_POST['accountLedgerID'] : '');
$accountNo        = (isset($_POST['accountNo']) ? $_POST['accountNo'] : '');
$accountName      = (isset($_POST['accountName']) ? $_POST['accountName'] : '');
//$accountMain    = (isset($_POST['accountMain']) ? $_POST['accountMain'] : '');
$openingBalance   = (isset($_POST['openingBalance']) ? $_POST['openingBalance'] : '');
$openingBalanceDate = (isset($_POST['openingBalanceDate']) ? $_POST['openingBalanceDate'] : '');
$selectable       = (isset($_POST['selectable']) ? $_POST['selectable'] : '');
$popUp            = (isset($_POST['popUp']) ? $_POST['popUp'] : '');
$accountChar      = (isset($_POST['accountChar']) ? $_POST['accountChar'] : '');
$active           = (isset($_POST['active']) ? $_POST['active'] : '');

$sqlCount   =   "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM tblAccAccounts
                 WHERE accountID = '" . $accountID . "'";
$GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sqlCount, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
    $total = $row ['TOTAL'];
}
if ($total > 0) // table returned some rows
    {
        $sqlUpdate= "UPDATE tblAccAccounts 
            SET accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "',
                accountNo = '" . $accountNo . "',
                accountName = '" . $accountName . "',
                openingBalance = '" . $openingBalance . "',
                openingBalanceDate = '" . $openingBalanceDate . "',
                selectable = '" . $selectable . "',
                popUp = '" . $popUp . "',
                accountChar = '" . $accountChar . "',
                active = '" . $active . "'
            WHERE accountID = '".$accountID."'"; 
        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlUpdate, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    } 
    else 
    { // no such row exists.
        $sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO tblAccAccounts
                        SET accountID = '" . $accountID . "',
                        accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "',
                        accountNo = '" . $accountNo . "',
                        accountName = '" . $accountName . "',
                        openingBalance = '" . $openingBalance . "',
                        openingBalanceDate = '" . $openingBalanceDate . "',
                        selectable = '" . $selectable . "',
                        popUp = '" . $popUp . "',
                        accountChar = '" . $accountChar . "', 
                        active = 'y',   
                        employeeID = '" . $employeeID . "',                         
                        propertyID = '" . $propertyID . "',                         
                        dateTimeEmployee = NOW() "; 
        $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlInsert, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    }}
```

> JavaScript

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#btnSave").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#btnSave").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    //var test = $("#accountLedger").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var accountLedgerID = $("#accountLedger").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    var accountID = $("#accountID").val();
    var accountName = $('#accountName').val();
    var accountNo = $("#accountNo").val();
    var openingBalance = $('#openingBalance').val();
    var openingBalanceDate = $('#openingBalanceDate').val();
    //var selectable = $("input[name=selectable]:checked").val(); 
    var selectable = $('#selectable').val(); 
    var popUp = $('#popUp').val();
    //var popUp = $("input[name=popUp]:checked").val();
    var accountChar = $("#accountChar").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getCoaGroup.php",
        type: "POST",
            data: {
                method: "editGroup",
                accountID: accountID,
                accountLedgerID: accountLedgerID,
                accountName: accountName,
                accountNo: accountNo,
                openingBalance: openingBalance,
                openingBalanceDate: openingBalanceDate,
                selectable: selectable,
                popUp: popUp,
                accountChar: accountChar
                },
                        success: function(){
                            KendoAlert("Data updated");
                        }
        });
    });
```

Anyone have opinion on this?

Comment: first you are updating the fields and then again using same accountID you are inserting a row. why?
and what is happening at this line `accountID= $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK(tblAccAccounts);` ?

Comment: Is it wrong to use the same? Sorry, I'm little bit confusing here @MukulKumarJha

Comment: No i'm just asking . 
Why are you performing the INSERT operation? as you only want to UPDATE the row ?

Comment: In my mind, it should be not update if the row is exist but if the row not exist it will insert the new row

Comment: About  accountID= $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK(tblAccAccounts); I have removed that.

Comment: you just need to check first if there is some row already existing in table or not . If yes, UPDATE it, if not , INSERT one .
but this should be done in *conditional style* @hikari

Comment: I have edited above the PHP update, can you take a look of that. It is correct? @MukulKumarJha

Comment: why is `not equal` in `"SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM tblAccAccounts
                 WHERE accountID != '" . $accountID . "'` ?
You need to get the row whose `accountID` is same as of yours and not different.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have edited the code. I think its working now @MukulKumarJha. Is it correct my code above?

Comment: It looks good @hikari

Comment: Thank you! I'm appreciate it @MukulKumarJha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just update the rows of tables you just need to perform a `UPDATE` query , there is no need to use `INSERT` afterwards.

which means there is no need to use this part of code

```
accountID= $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK(tblAccAccounts);
$sqlAdd     =   "INSERT INTO tblAccAccounts
                SET accountID = '" . $accountID . "',
                accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "',
                accountNo = '" . $accountNo . "',
                accountName = '" . $accountName . "',
                openingBalance = '" . $openingBalance . "',
                openingBalanceDate = '" . $openingBalanceDate . "',
                selectable = '" . $selectable . "',
                popUp = '" . $popUp . "',
                accountChar = '" . $accountChar . "', 
                active = 'y',   
                employeeID = '" . $employeeID . "',                         
                propertyID = '" . $propertyID . "',                         
                dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);    }
```

Also if you want to (which you should be) `INSERT` a new row if there is no existing row in the table you should be doing that only *after performing a check on the table* .

for example :

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tblAccAccounts WHERE AccountID = $accountID");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) // table returned some rows
{
    $sqlUpdate= <YOUR UPDATE COMMAND HERE>;
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlUpdate);

} 
 else { // no such row exists.
    $sqlInsert=<YOUR INSERT COMMAND HERE>;
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqlInsert);
}
```